# SQL Error on date, whats the correct format to upload seperate date and time?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to know what the problem with my PHP code is and why SQL is throwing this error.
The date and time format look fine in comparison to other articles I have looked at.

**Error**

> insert story failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds   to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near ':21:20, planning)' at line 2

**PHP**

```
$insertStoryData = "INSERT INTO `story` (story_name, story_text, story_point, uploader_name, story_date, story_time, phase)
                VALUES ($escaped_story_name, $escaped_story_text, $escaped_story_point, $escaped_uploader_name, $escaped_story_date, $escaped_story_time, $escaped_phase)";

$insertResult = mysqli_query($db, $insertStoryData)
    or die("insert story failed" . mysqli_error($db));
```

**What format the date and time are**

```
21/9/2013 - Date
19:21:20 - Time
```

**Story date and Story time SQL fields**

story_date is of type date and story_time is of type time

The time and date are produced by the JavaScript before an AJAX request to the PHP script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Date on mysql follow the format: yyyy-mm-dd

Time on mysql follow the format: hh:ii:ss

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose the date and the time in single quotes (separately of course). Also, your date format is incorrect - it needs to be yyyy-mm-dd.